# Where is the inflection point for a pair of logistic functions

Tags: functions

Consider a special case of the logistic function:

$$f(x, x_0) = \frac{1}{1+e^{x - x_0}}$$

Let us define an operation on a pair of logistic functions $f(x, x_0) \oplus f(x, x_1)$ as $f(x, x_0) + f(x, x_1) - f(x, x_0) f(x, x_1)$.  As an example, if $x_0=0$, $x_1 = 1$ we get the following plot.

[image]

Assuming the point of inflection is always still at $y=0.5$, I would like to know where $f(x, x_0) \oplus f(x, x_1) = 0.5$.  How can you calculate that as function of $x_0$ and $x_1$.

Comment: By looking at your chart, it should be about $1.5$.  If you let $u = e^x$, you can turn $f(x, x_0) \oplus f(x, x_1) = 0.5$ into a quadratic equation in $u$ and get the positive solution $u=\frac{1+e+\sqrt{1+6e+e^2}}{2} \approx 4.344$ and so $x=\log_e(u)\approx 1.4688$

Comment: @Henry Thank you. I really meant as a function of $x_0$ and $x_1$

Comment: You will still get a quadratic in general, which might look simpler if you use $u_0=e^{x_0}$ and $u_1=e^{x_1}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set $u=e^{x}$ and $u_0=e^{x_0}$ and $u_1=e^{x_1}$ then you want to solve $$\frac1{1+u/u_0}+\frac1{1+u/u_1}-\frac1{1+u/u_0}\frac1{1+u/u_1}=\frac12$$ for $u$ and then let $x=\log_e(u)$.  This is a quadratic in $u$, but you only want the positive root, which is $$u=\frac{u_0+u_1+\sqrt{u_0^2+6u_0u_1+u_1^2}}{2}.$$
Similarly you could also find solutions for other values of $y$.

In your example of $x_0=0$ and $x_1=1$, this gives $x=\log_e\left(\frac{1+e+\sqrt{1+6e+e^2}}{2}\right) \approx 1.4688$, which is consistent with your chart.

Comment: Thank you but I am looking for an answer in terms of $x_0$ and $x_1$. Your comment above looks helpful.

Comment: @Simd: $x=\log_e\left(\dfrac{e^{x_0}+e^{x_1}+\sqrt{e^{2x_0}+6e^{x_0x_1}+e^{2x_1}}}{2}\right)$ but less obvious what is going on

Comment: If $x_1 \gg x_0$ then this should be approximately $x_1$ which it does seem to be, I think. Is that right?

Comment: That is correct:  the amount it exceeds $x_1$ is a function of  $x_1 - x_0$ and is close to $0$ unless $x_0$ is close to $x_1$

Comment: The formula in your answer has a term $6e$ which seems correct. However in your comment you have $6e^{x_0 x_1} = 6$ when $x_0=0$ and $x_1 =1$.  I think that is a mistake.

Comment: I think it should be $e^{x_0 + x_1}$.

Comment: @Simd Yes, you are correct.  It was $u_0u_1=e^{x_0}e^{x_1}$ and so the comment should have $x=\log_e\left(\dfrac{e^{x_0}+e^{x_1}+\sqrt{e^{2x_0}+6e^{x_0+x_1}+e^{2x_1}}}{2}\right)$